# C# web server doesn't see stored cookies

Tags: c#, facebook, cookies, httpwebrequest

I'm writing a little test snippet of C# code which logs into Facebook and captures cookies. I'm doing it for educational purposes only. I have been given a task to automate form uploads, downloads, and form submissions between my work and a third party, and it's one of those things where I have to get it right, and I have to get it right the first time; hence why I thought I'd do a little practice with Facebook and some other web services.

I have:

```
string postMessage = "user=" + username + "&pass=" + password;
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
MessageBox.Show(cookieJar.Count + " cookies"); // 0 cookies, as expected.

HttpWebRequest wReq
 = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.facebook.com/login.php");
wReq.Proxy             = HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
wReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wReq.UserAgent
  = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 "
  + "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.65 Safari/534.24";
wReq.CookieContainer   = cookieJar;
wReq.Method            = "POST";
wReq.ContentLength     = postMessage.Length;
wReq.ContentType       = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

StreamWriter sw = null;

try
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(wReq.GetRequestStream());
    sw.Write(postMessage);
}
catch
{
    return false;
}
finally
{
    sw.Close();
}

string result = string.Empty;

HttpWebResponse wResp  = (HttpWebResponse)wReq.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close(); // BREAKPOINT 1
}

MessageBox.Show(cookieJar.Count + " cookies"); // 6 cookies.

wReq
  = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com/home.php");
wReq.Proxy = HttpWebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
wReq.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
wReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 "
  + "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.65 Safari/534.24";
wReq.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

result = string.Empty;

wResp = (HttpWebResponse)wReq.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wResp.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close(); // BREAKPOINT 2
}
```

If I check `result` at breakpoint 1, I can see result contains the html code for Facebook's log in page. It is telling me that cookies are not enabled in my browser, even though my `cookiaJar` has captured 6 cookies.

Similarly, if I check `result` at breakpoint 2, I can see html code which is telling me "I have to log in to see this page".

Now, I know Facebook works without JavaScript, and I am capturing 6 cookies in my `cookieJar`. I'm a little confused why this isn't working?

(By the way, my password has upper case, lower case, numbers and symbols. Do I need to encode it with `URLEncode()`? I have successfully logged into a different website using a plain text password without encoding the password.)

Answer (score 1):

You switch from https for the login to http for the read.  Try changing the second read to use https as well and see if that helps.